# Can compilation and display of species frequency data be improved using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, csv, display

I am new to QGIS 1.8.0.

I would like to find out if the way I put a species frequency map together could be improved upon.

I had to map the presence or absence of 7 plant species surveyed in 30 2m x 2m quadrats. This data was saved in separate csv files for each species. I then table joined a single csv file to a single vector layer consisting of a 2m grid polygon. The unique ID for the table join involved zooming in on the 2m grid to identify where the survey quadrat had been placed and noting down the polygon identifier number using the identify feature tool. This number was then input as an extra field in the plant species spreadsheet before saving as a csv file.

The final product consists of an background Ordnance Survey 50k Raster map, 7 x 2m grid polygon vector layers each joined to one of 7 x csv files.

Although this has achieved the desired product, I am convinced there must be a slicker way of reaching the same end result, particularly in reducing the number of polygon layers used.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the currently available functionality, I think you will have the easiest time working and sharing your data with others if you have seven polygon files. Since the polygons are quite simple and few, it shouldn't be a problem of storage space.

Alternatively, you can have one polygon file but load it 7 times into the project. Always join it with only one CSV. Saves disk space and you can enable/disable species as you want.